# Why is the Displace modifier moving my mesh instead of moving the geometry?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, displacement

When I am using the Displace modifier, my whole mesh moves up or down on the Z axis, but the mesh isn't actually displaced.

[image]

I am trying to use an image to displace the geometry of the mesh. But the geometry is staying flat. What am I not seeing?

Blend:

[image]

Comment: please pack the image on the blend file

Comment: to use the displace modifier read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454

Comment: Use UV coordinates: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVfoy.png

Comment: I cannot find how to pack the image on file :(

Comment: **File-External Data-Pack all into .Blend** , then save the file again.

Comment: realted: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry/42641#42641 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/why-does-image-texture-used-in-displace-modifier-not-give-the-correct-height/33437#33437 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45335/displacement-modifier-and-texture-coordinates/45385#45385 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31350/re-do-view-of-a-photo-via-dem-data-and-blender/31352#31352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your textures tab, select the drop down called "Image Texture" and select under Modifiers "Displace"

[image: Texture tab]

In the new tab select the button called "Open" under image and select your desired image.

[image: Open your image]

There, should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't displace the mesh

Comment: @fabriced Done.

Comment: Please show the textures you are using in a Blender Screen Image.  The file have posted does not have images.  They are not packed into the Blender file.  Do you have the textures on your hard disk?  Did someone send you a file?

Comment: Thanks the photos really helped! Although the method isn't really precise, is it? Or do I have to give the mesh a larger number of subdivisions? But won't that slow down everything?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Did you mean to post this as a comment to the question?

Comment: @fabriced You do have to use a lot of sub divs if you want it to be precise, but generally this is used for making things seem more naturally bumpy. You could use bump maps that are a lovely thing or just project the image on to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your textures are visible.
Make sure you use a high density mesh.
UV Map both planes if you are planning to use them. Use UV Map.

When I used my own textures and UV Mapped I saw displacement. For the single flat plane I created a high density mesh with Control R and I saw some displacement. You have two planes in your file.